# Cannot publish my SharePoint MVC app project in VS

Tags: provider-hosted-app, mvc, visual-studio-2015, pnp, pnp-provision

I created in VS2015 a new App. VS will create automatically an app project and an MVC web project. Inside my MVC web project I have an template xml file as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2016/05/ProvisioningSchema">
  <pnp:Preferences Generator="OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=2.7.1609.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3751622786b357c2" />
  <pnp:Templates ID="CONTAINER-TEMPLATE-819C564282654030A12C73A642964170">
    <pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="TEMPLATE-819C564282654030A12C73A642964170" Version="1" BaseSiteTemplate="BLANKINTERNET#0">
      <pnp:WebSettings NoCrawl="false"  WelcomePage="Paginas/Home.aspx" SiteLogo="" AlternateCSS="" MasterPageUrl="{masterpagecatalog}/BM.Intern.Werkruimte/Masterpage.Intern.Werkruimte.master" CustomMasterPageUrl="{masterpagecatalog}/BM.Intern.Werkruimte/Masterpage.Intern.Werkruimte.master" />
      <pnp:RegionalSettings AdjustHijriDays="0" AlternateCalendarType="None" CalendarType="Gregorian" Collation="25" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" FirstWeekOfYear="0" LocaleId="1043" ShowWeeks="false" Time24="true" TimeZone="3" WorkDayEndHour="5:00PM" WorkDays="62" WorkDayStartHour="8:00AM" />
      <pnp:SupportedUILanguages>
        <pnp:SupportedUILanguage LCID="1043" />
      </pnp:SupportedUILanguages>
      <pnp:Files>
        <pnp:File Src="Home.aspx" Folder="{site}/Paginas" Overwrite="true">
          <pnp:Properties>
            <pnp:Property Key="ContentTypeId" Value="{contenttypeid:Welkomstpagina}" />
            <pnp:Property Key="Title" Value="Home" />
            <pnp:Property Key="PublishingPageLayout" Value="{masterpagecatalog}/BlankWebPartPage.aspx, Lege pagina met webonderdelen" />
            <pnp:Property Key="PublishingIsFurlPage" Value="False" />
            <pnp:Property Key="RobotsNoIndex" Value="False" />
            <pnp:Property Key="PublishingPageContent" Value="&lt;h1&gt;​​Welkom op de Periode!&lt;{site}h1&gt;" />
          </pnp:Properties>
        </pnp:File>
      </pnp:Files>
      <pnp:Navigation>
        <pnp:GlobalNavigation />
        <pnp:CurrentNavigation />
      </pnp:Navigation>
    </pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
  </pnp:Templates>
</pnp:Provisioning>
```

In the same folder as where I have stored my template xml file I have also a blanco publishing page named Home.aspx. This is the content of Home.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> 
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
    <head>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,Comments,PublishingStartDate,PublishingExpirationDate,PublishingContactEmail,PublishingContactName,PublishingContactPicture,PublishingPageLayout,PublishingVariationGroupID,PublishingVariationRelationshipLinkFieldID,PublishingRollupImage,Audience,PublishingIsFurlPage,PublishingPageImage,PublishingPageContent,SummaryLinks,SummaryLinks2,SeoBrowserTitle,SeoMetaDescription,SeoKeywords,RobotsNoIndex"><xml>
        <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
        <mso:PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">1</mso:PublishingContact>
        <mso:PublishingIsFurlPage msdt:dt="string">0</mso:PublishingIsFurlPage>
        <mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">Bart Donninger</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact>
        <mso:PublishingContactPicture msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactPicture>
        <mso:RobotsNoIndex msdt:dt="string">0</mso:RobotsNoIndex>
        <mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390064DEA0F50FC8C147B0B6EA0636C4A7D400B00B6B5176D4C343A182CF31E3D2BE00</mso:ContentTypeId>
        <mso:Comments msdt:dt="string"></mso:Comments>
        <mso:PublishingContactEmail msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactEmail>
        <mso:RequiresRouting msdt:dt="string">False</mso:RequiresRouting>
        </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
        </xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->
        <title>Home</title>
   </head>
</html>
```

Here is the pnp CSOM code to do the ProvisioningTemplate:

```
private bool ApplyProvisioningTemplate(Web newWeb)
        {
            XMLTemplateProvider provider = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(String.Format(@"{0}\Templates\", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "");

            if (provider != null)
            {
                var template = provider.GetTemplate("periodeTemplate.xml");
                template.Connector = provider.Connector;

                if (template != null)
                {
                    newWeb.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(template);

                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

I can do a build on the solution. But when I try to publish the MVC web project I get build errors:

> The file '/Templates/~TemplatePageUrl' does not exist.
>
> The file '/Templates/~masterurl/custom.master' does not exist.

Why do I got this build errors when I do a publish? When I do a build I dont get them. And what is the best practice to create a new publishing page by TemplateProvisioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another solution which is better than my previous solution. In your Visual Studio you have publish profiles. In your publish profile you can go to settings. Disable the option: **Precompile during publishing**. Now you can publish your MVC web project without errors about the SharePoint token in the VirtualPath.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use the SharePoint token **~TemplatePageUrl** in the virtualPath.

I fixed it by my self. I renamed the Home.aspx to Home.txt. Now I can do a publish. After the publish I use gulp to create a deployment package. Inside gulp js code I rename the Home.txt back to Home.aspx. Here is my gulp js code:

```
gulp.task('fixPublishingPages', function () {
    gulp.src(outputFolderWeb + 'Templates/Pages/*.txt')
      .pipe(rename(function (path) {
          path.extname = ".aspx"
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolderWeb + 'Templates/Pages'));
    del(outputFolderWeb + 'Templates/Pages/*.txt', { force: true });
});
```